# Чтение pdf файла и вывод его в тело html документа

Tags: pdf, php

Как на php можно реализовать чтение и вывод содержимого pdf файла в тело html документа?

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял то, что вам нужно.

- Просто конвертировать PDF в HTML (**pdftohtml** и подобные), обычно результат - не очень.
- Использовать отрисовку PDF какой-либо утилитой (вроде **poppler**).